# Ant / HSQLDB: Tables not created / found

Tags: ant, hsqldb

Good morning

I want to generate database documentation during the ant build. Therefore I startup HSLQDB (version 2.3.0) and initialize it from a dump generated during the unit tests. I do this like so:

```
<property name="database.name" value="testdb" /> 
  <property name="database.url.cache" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/testdb;sql.syntax_ora=true" /> 
  <echo message="- hsqldb initialize -" /> 
  <java classname="org.hsqldb.Server" fork="true" spawn="true" classpathref="db.classpath"> 
     <arg value="-database.0"/> 
     <arg value="file:${database.dir}/${database.name}"/> 
     <arg value="-dbname.0"/> 
     <arg value="${database.name}"/> 
     <arg value="-port"/> 
     <arg value="9001"/> 
  </java> 
  <property name="jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" /> 
    <property name="database.username" value="sa" /> 
    <property name="database.password" value="" /> 
    <sql 
      classpathref="db.classpath" 
      driver="${jdbc.driver}" 
      url="${database.url.cache}" 
      userid="${database.username}" password="${database.password}" 
      autocommit="true"> 
      SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE; 
    </sql>
```

This works perfectly as long as ran locally. But on the buildserver I am not allowed to open any ports (neither to execute any jars that might hang and mess up the subsequent builds). Therefore I want to start HSQLDB inmemory which is done by setting

```
-address jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
```

Of course this kills the schema since the file is ignored. But when I insert any tables into the inmemory database with:

```
<sql 
   classpathref="db.classpath" 
   driver="${jdbc.driver}" 
   url="${database.url.cache}" 
   userid="${database.username}" password="${database.password}" 
   autocommit="true" src="anydir/anyfile.sql">
</sql>
```

anyfile.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE test (ID DECIMAL(19) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, TESTME VARCHAR2(255));
```

...nothing happens. When I query the database no tables are available:

```
<sql 
   classpathref="db.classpath" 
   driver="${jdbc.driver}" 
   url="${database.url.cache}" 
   userid="${database.username}" password="${database.password}" 
   autocommit="true">
   SCRIPT 'anydir/hsqldb.dump';
</sql>
```

There are no tables in schema PUBLIC at all which means it's a fresh database...

What am I doing wrong? I already tried the params (e.g. shutdown=true) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349168/hsqldb-manage-a-new-standalone-database-with-ant-table-not-found-in-statement).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between "not server" and "in memory". You can run a server on a in-memory database as well as running no server with the file variant. However it is a good thing to try to use in-memory for testing if possible. You avoid the need to cleanup and it is faster.

If you want to use in-memory, you need to initialize it from within your running java process. That is not something you can do with an external ANT script. You also should make sure you do not close the last connection, or to switch that feature off (DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1). This should also work within the same ANT Job (=JVM). You should also use a named mem instance so all ant tasks meet in the same memory region.

I have a [unit test](https://github.com/ecki/seeburger-vfs2/blob/master/vfs2provider-jdbctable/src/test/java/com/seeburger/vfs2/provider/jdbctable/test/H2ProviderTestCase.java#L102) which is using Flyway to initialize a in-memory H2 and run the tests, the initializer looks like:

```
JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
ds.setUser("VFSTEST");
ds.setPassword("secret");
// make sure "mem" database is not anonymous and 
// will not get dropped on connection close
ds.setURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;JMX=TRUE");
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(ds);
flyway.setLocations("db/migration/h2_derby");    
flyway.setValidateOnMigrate(true);
flyway.setCleanOnValidationError(true);
flyway.migrate();
// now use "ds".
```